# How to leave a usb port powered during shutdown for charging mobile?

Tags: drivers, usb, power-management, hardware, vaio

My [Sony VAIO Laptop](http://www.sony.co.in/product/svf14212sn) has a feature which will allow me to keep one USB port powered even when my laptop is shut down. It is given in the manual [here](http://docs.esupport.sony.com/pc/SVS1311_13A1_1511_series/EN/contents/03/12/12/12.html). It can be switched on or off from the Vaio software which came with pre-installed Windows.

In the past, when I was dual booting with Windows, I could enable it by booting into Windows, and it would stay on, even after using Ubuntu several times. For some reason it stopped working recently. But I don't have Windows anymore, and would like to re-enable it from Ubuntu. It would be fun if I could switch it on manually from Linux. I digged a lot on google, especially for information on my motherboard(HannStar J MV-6 94V-0), and came up with its [schematics in a Vietnamese site](http://kythuatphancung.vn/download/sony-vaio-svf14-quanta-hk8-laptop-schematics.html). I specifically mentions USB charging. But I am having no idea as to how to use the information.

Lot of people are suggesting that it can be **enabled from the BIOS**, but I have checked again and do not see anything in the BIOS. But I also observed that BIOS has very few fields, making me suspect that BIOS features might be hidden. I will try to unlock them. In the mean time, output of `dmidecode` is appended towards end of the question.

I don't know if this feature requires special hardware support, but anyways it is possible on my machine. Smart phones tend to go low on battery fast, and you could always connect it to the laptop in your bag, and charge it on the move when you are in college or traveling. That would not only be cool and handy, but also save money because I wont have to buy a power bank.

Here is the collected data:

- [`dmidecode` output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11539421/)
- [Kernel messages (loading `sony-laptop` with `debug=1`)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11569807/)
- [Content of `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/` and `/proc/acpi/`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11539548/)
- After upgrading to `3.16.0-38-generic` as suggested by Sneetsher,, uploaded new the [kernel messages](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11569807/)

  Also after the upgrage, I see `usb_charge`, but with value `1` of:

  ```
    cat /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/usb_charge
  ```

  but when I tried toggling it to `0` It still does not activate USB charging, but simply resets back to `1`  when I check again using `cat`. But it should have worked  because I found a [c program](https://github.com/norbusan/sony-control-center/blob/master/sony-setter/sony-setter.c) and [a shell script](https://gist.github.com/Totto8492/4585cbc233ae8d7cc1bc) doing the same. I've noticed that I can write only 0 and one and if I write something else like suppose 2, I'll get:

  tee: /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/usb_charge: Invalid argument
- [Content of `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/` and `/proc/acpi/` after kernel upgrade.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11569886/)

I manually booted into kernel 3.18, but the issue is still there. By the guidance of Sneetsher, I've filed a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1461986).

Comment: Most laptops will charge a previously-connected device when in sleep mode, but the shut-down charge is a hardware feature. You could try running the control software using Wine.

Comment: Never thought of that, will use wine, but only as last resort. Is there no way by which I can accomplish this manually?

Comment: Maybe in your BIOS settings.

Comment: So your only option is either a Linux program or the possibility that the Windows version will work.

Comment: It might be, but Linux probably doesn't have the capability if there's no program for it.

Comment: @Zacharee1, maybe there is no program because it is not a general feature, ie, present on every laptop. I've updated the question with motherboard information.

Comment: Wine and USB is no good idea usually. I am sorry, but it is always a problem to make wine apps recognize USB ports, so I doubt it will work. You should try it, but don't expect too much.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there has to be a BIOS setting for this somewhere (did you check the advanced section)? This is called a "sleep and charge" usb port. I think the "VAIO Control Center" just toggles a BIOS setting somehow. There may be a way to do with from within Linux, but I don't know enough about that. Look into `dmidecode` and `smbios` as perhaps that may point you in the right direction? Note that other brands of laptops have these types of USB ports and they work with Ubuntu (so long as they are enabled via BIOS).

Answer (score 7):

It's better to start where others stopped with `sony-laptop` Linux kernel module.

1. Check if it's loaded

   ```
   lsmod | grep sony
   ```
2. If not, load it

   ```
   sudo modprobe sony-laptop
   ```
3. Check if there any corresponding entry/function for USB charging (`usb_charge` attribute got from source):

   ```
   tree /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/
   ```

   As I check the driver source, here are the corresponding functions (may be not for all models):

   ```
   ...
   static int sony_nc_usb_charge_setup(struct platform_device *pd);
   static void sony_nc_usb_charge_cleanup(struct platform_device *pd);
   ...
   ```

   Full functions definition [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11546536/) (portion from [`sony-laptop.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/x86/sony-laptop.c))

   `0x0155` seems to be detected on you laptop from the [kernel messages](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11539428/). The module created `touchpad`, `battery_care_limiter`, read-only `handles`, read-only `battery_care_health` SYSFS attributes but nothing else (including `usb_charge`).

   I checked the Ubuntu kernel source looking for USB charge function:

   - Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty (not yet added), kernel version 3.13

     If you are using this release, the easiest way is to install Utopic kernel:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
     ```
   - Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic (it's there), kernel version 3.16

   If it is not there, it is hard/risky only if you are up to:

   > ```
   > Development:
   > ------------
   >
   > If you want to help with the development of this driver (and
   > you are not afraid of any side effects doing strange things with
   > your ACPI BIOS could have on your laptop), load the driver and
   > pass the option 'debug=1'.
   >
   > REPEAT: DON'T DO THIS IF YOU DON'T LIKE RISKY BUSINESS.
   >
   > In your kernel logs you will find the list of all ACPI methods
   > the SNC device has on your laptop.
   > ```

   See [Readme file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/laptops/sony-laptop.txt).
4. As kernel upgraded by OP to 3.16.0-38-generic, `usb_charge` is created with some other SYSFS attributes.

   Reading similar driver kernel docs, [sysfs-driver-samsung-laptop](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-driver-samsung-laptop):

   > ```
   > What:     /sys/devices/platform/samsung/usb_charge
   > Date:     December 1, 2011
   > KernelVersion:    3.3
   > Contact:  Corentin Chary <corentin.chary@gmail.com>
   > Description:  Use your USB ports to charge devices, even
   >       when your laptop is powered off.
   >       1 means enabled, 0 means disabled.
   > ```

   To check current state:

   ```
   cat /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/usb_charge
   ```

   To disable it:

   ```
   echo 0 | sudo tee -a /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/usb_charge
   ```

   To enable it:

   ```
   echo 1 | sudo tee -a /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/usb_charge
   ```

**References:**

- [Sony Notebook Control Driver (SNC) Readme](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/laptops/sony-laptop.txt)
- [`sony-laptop` source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/x86/sony-laptop.c#L171)

Comment: Strange enough, after upgrading to `3.18.3-031803-generic`, I see usb_charge, but with value 1!

Comment: I've updated the question to the end with what you asked for and a bit more info, to the end, and note that I changed the value by `echo 0 | sudo tee -a /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/usb_charge`.

Comment: @user3073656, Ok, you can join me here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24450/discussion-between-sneetsher-user3073656

Comment: I've awarded you the full bounty, because even though did not solve the issue fully, pointed  me in the right direction.