# I want to charge an iPod while in Suspend

Tags: dual-boot, usb, suspend, power-management, ipod

Sony Vaio VGN-FW250j

Intel Core 2 Duo P8400

dual boot Win 7 / Ubuntu 15.04

I am able to suspend and hibernate this laptop in both OSes.  Ubuntu will not allow me to use the USB ports to charge my iPod while the computer is in suspend mode and connected to AC. This option is available to me in Win 7 and the iPod indeed charges.

I am fairly certain this is something I could control, or should be able to control via a config change in some file. I just don't know where to begin.  I have scoured this and many other forums but the answers and questions are too technical or they have differences to the point it seems it does not apply to me.  I don't want to mess anything up by making a guess and then have some unknown issue later that I have no clue and baffles me for years.

Can someone please help me understand how to do this?

At this time I am studying the information from this link:

[How to leave a usb port powered during shutdown for charging mobile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628542/how-to-leave-a-usb-port-powered-during-shutdown-for-charging-mobile?rq=1)